# Chrome headless does not support Chrome Policies from registry

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, kerberos, google-chrome-headless, kerberos-delegation

I am using Google Chrome (v.65 stable) to access a company intranet site which uses kerberos credential authentication. To do this I edited the registry Google Chrome Policies to the following:

```
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*.intranet.net,*.intranet2.net"
"AuthServerWhitelist"="*.intranet.net,*.intranet2.net"
"AuthSchemes"="basic,digest,ntlm,negotiate"
```

This allows me to successfully access the intranet site. I have been able to automate some processes on the kerberos-enabled intranet site using Selenium Chromedriver (with the GUI Chrome browser viewable). However, if I use Chrome in "headless" mode, I am returned with

> Error: HTTP 401 Authentication Required.

and a message that kerberos credential delegation is not enabled.  Python code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension',False)

#added for headless chrome
chrome_options.set_headless()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://intranet.net')
```

Can Chrome headless incorporate registry Google Chrome Policies?

Comment: Did you get it working ?.

Comment: unfortunately no, although support for integrated authentication in headless was supposed to be added in [chrome M65](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=741872#c29),  it does not appear to have been done... Or at least it is not working for me still

Comment: I ended up just using HTTP GET and POST with python requests and requests_kerberos modules to interact and send form data, which is the majority of what I was doing with the web driver anyways. Which is probably more robust and better practice anyways... but I wish it could have worked with the headless chrome!